# this is null in React class function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I refactored a React class of mine from ES5 to ES6 and now when I click a button, which calls `this.state.dispatch(logIn(this.state.logIn))`, the initial `this` at the beginning of the line is null. Super weird.

Here's my class:

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            panelIsOpen: false,
            registration: {},
            login: {},
        };
    }

    signUp() {
        this.props.dispatch(signUp(this.state.registration));

        this.setState({
            registration: {},
        });
    }

    logIn() {
        debugger; // this is `null here`
        this.props.dispatch(logIn(this.state.login));

        this.setState({
            login: {},
        });
    }

    togglePanel(e) {
        this.setState({ panelIsOpen: !this.state.panelIsOpen} );
    }

    render() {
        const {elements} = this.props;
        const {registration, login} = this.state;

        return (
            // some stuff 
        );
    }
};

Home.propTypes = {
    elements: React.PropTypes.array,
    dispatch: React.PropTypes.func,
    user: React.PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = ({elements, auth}) => {
    return {
        elements: getElementsByKeyName(elements, 'visibleElements'),
        user: getLoggedInUser(auth),
    };
};

Home = DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(Home);
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

Clicking the log in button calls the login function but for some reason here, `this` is `null`

Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React doesn't bind the context of methods that are added to ES6 classes unless they're part of the standard React lifecycle (`componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentDidMount`, and so on).

What this means is that you need to either manually bind the value of `this` for your `signUp`, `logIn` and `togglePanel` methods, or else declare them as arrow functions, which inherit the parent context.

1.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this);
  this.logIn = this.logIn.bind(this);
  this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);

  this.state = {
    panelIsOpen: false,
    registration: {},
    login: {},
  }
```

or

2.

```
signUp = () => {
  this.props.dispatch(signUp(this.state.registration));

  this.setState({
    registration: {},
  });
}

// the same for logIn and togglePanel
```

For reference, see [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html).

Comment: I guess I was taking that for granted when I was using `createClass`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This (no pun intended) has to do with how functions are bound in ES6. If you're passing your method as a prop to another component, the context it's run in isn't guaranteed to be the right context (unless you bind it first). Here's an article with a long, but interesting read on it: http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/

In short, you have a couple options:

1. (pretty common/popular) bind your methods to this in the constructor. You might not need to bind all your methods - depends how they're being used.

   ```
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           panelIsOpen: false,
           registration: {},
           login: {},
       };
       this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this);
       this.signUp = this.logIn.bind(this);
       this.togglePannel = this.togglePannel.bind(this);
   }
   ```
2. Define your methods as arrow functions which will bind it to the current scope for you - no need to bind them in the constructor:

   ```
   class Home extends Component {
       // ...

       signUp = () => {
           this.props.dispatch(signUp(this.state.registration));

           this.setState({
               registration: {},
           });
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks James. Nice pun ;)